# Issue ordering array in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm trying to order a column inside array but is not ordering is showing values without ordering by lastname ASC.

Here is my table:

```
|products|
  |id| |money| |client_id|
   1     1000      1
   2     2000      4
   3     2000      7
   4     2000      5
   5     2000      6
   6     2000      3
   7     2000      2

|customers|
  |id| |name|    |lastname1|    |lastname2|
   1    Lionel     Messi        Bueno
   2    Cristiano  Ronaldo      Tiger
   3    Cecs       Fabregas     Midtlon
   4    Andres     Iniesta      Blanco
   5    Neymar     Dos Santos   Junior
```

Here is my controller

```
class ProductController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products= Product.all
  end
end
```

Here is the model

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products

  def str_name
     return lastname1.to_s+" "+lastname2.to_s+" "+name.to_s
  end
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :client
end
```

Here is my view

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Money</td>
    <td>Client</td>     
  </tr>

  <% @products.each do |p| %>
  <tr> 
    <td><%= p.money %></td>
    <td><%= p.str_name %></td>
  <% end %>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

I tried but is not ordering by lastname1 asc:

```
  <% @products.each do |p| %>
  <tr> 
    <td><%= p.money %></td>
    <td><% @a= p.client(:order=>"lastname1 ASC")%> <%= @a.str_name %></td>
  <% end %>
```

The log is:

```
 SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE (`clients`.`id` = 1)
 SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE (`clients`.`id` = 2)
 SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE (`clients`.`id` = 3)
 SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE (`clients`.`id` = 4)
```

And should be like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM `clients` order by last_name1 ASC
```

Please somebody can help me?

Comment: Don't do `<% @a= p.client(:order=>"lastname1 ASC")%>` in a view. Do it in a controller, and access `@a` in the view.

Comment: @the thin man how could be the correct answer ? Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% @a= p.client(:order=>"lastname1 ASC")%> <%= @a.str_name %></td>
```

The line above does technically nothing. When you are already in the loop and you ask for the client of the current product, how many is it going to return? Only one, right ? Right, if you have a belongs_to on the other side (which I hope you do, this answer relies on it). So you're actually "sorting" a set of one element every iteration. And that's why your Select is ignoring the "order by". What you should be doing though, is to get a list of all the products ordered by their respective clients' "lastname1". This should not be done in a view like you're trying to do, but in your controller. In your controller:

```
#In Rails 4
@products = Product.joins(:client).order('clients.lastname1 ASC')

#Other version (be careful where to use plurals and where not to)
@products = Product.find(:all, :joins => :client, :order => 'clients.lastname1 ASC')
```

And in your view:

```
<% @products.each do |p| %>
  <tr> 
    <td><%= p.money %></td>
    <td><%= p.client.str_name %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks , I tested the code according to that and worked , thank you mister, you are so smart.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <% @products.each do |p| %>
  <tr> 
    <td><%= p.money %></td>
    <td><% @a= p.client(:order=>"lastname1 ASC")%> <%= @a.str_name %></td>
  <% end %>
```

Not sure if this answers your question, but in the second `td`, the ERB tag isn't printing out anything to the page. Check your syntax.

If you're actually trying to set `@a` equal to something like that, it's best done in the controller.

That was just something I noticed. I'll continue to look at your code to see if I can find why you're not getting the result you desire.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, it looks like each product only has one client, however I can't be sure since you did not post code for your Product model. If that is the case, then `p.client` will only ever return one client, and there is no reason to sort the results; ActiveRecord may be smart enough to skip that step. This could also explain the queries in your log.

If you want a many-to-many relationship between clients and products, you should create a join table.

```
rails generate model ClientProduct client_id:integer product_id:integer
```

Your resulting relationships would be

Client:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :client_products
  has_many :products, :through => :client_products
  ...
end
```

Product:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :client_products
  has_many :clients, :through => :client_products
  ...
end
```

ClientProduct:

```
class ClientProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :product
  ...
end
```